# view pager loads three views at a time,how to get the reference to visible view?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

```
    class MyPagerAdaptor extends PagerAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyPagerAdaptor(){
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mIdList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*if(flag)
        {
            mPosToShare = position;
            System.out.println("mPosToShare......: "+mPosToShare);
            flag = false;
        }*/
        System.out.println("instantiateView............."+position);
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, viewGroup, false);
        ImageViewTouch imageView = (ImageViewTouch) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

        try 
        {
            InputStream is = mExpansionFile.getInputStream("worlatlaspronewmaps/"+title[1]+mIdList.get(position)+".jpg");
            //InputStream is1 = mExpansionFile.getInputStream("worlatlaspronewmaps/"+title[1]+mIdList.get(position-1)+".jpg");
            if(is == null)
            {
                is = mExpansionFile.getInputStream("worlatlaspronewmaps/"+title[1]+mIdList.get(position)+".JPG");
            }

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,bfOptions);
            System.out.println(bitmap);

            imageView.zoomTo(0.5f,50);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }  
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        viewGroup.addView(imageLayout,0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (view==object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

MyPagerAdaptor class is populating the viewpager with bitmap as pager's every view contains an imageview, but when i get the reference of bitmap it gives the reference of the right or left bitmap which is not visible. i need the bitmap reference which is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
objectOfViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

This returns the current item, indexed from 0.

EDIT : 
You can get the reference to the view like this,

```
int index = objectOfViewPager.getCurrentItem();
View view = objectOfViewPager.getChildAt(index);
```

EDIT 2 : (explaining further )

Since all you want to do is change the bitmap , here is what you should do:

```
int index = objectOfViewPager.getCurrentItem();
mIdList.set(index,whateverBitmapyouwant);
objectOfAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Ok its fine i get the current visible position of view. How can i get the reference to the bitmap at this position as every page in the view pager is an imageview and have a bitmap on it i need the that bitmap reference so that i can use it elsewhere? I think u got What i want.

Comment: i had seen your edited answer but it gives null to View reference **please help me friend**

Comment: i just need the reference of visible Image as bitmap..Means the image i am looking on viewpager which is in front of me..that i wanna share to someone. and my **mIdList** is not a map or something but simple an arraylist. :(

Comment: i know that mdList is an arraylist that is why I suggested the set() method. Anyways, in that case int index = objectOfViewPager.getCurrentItem();
View view = objectOfViewPager.getChildAt(index); will return the entire view. this will be the ViewGroup, inside which you will find the ImageLayout inside which you will have the ImageLayout.

Comment: still dint got my answer :((((((((((

Comment: is der anyone who can help me out for this please